# javascript await resolve order

Tags: typescript, es6-promise

Is it right to assume that `async` will "unlock" the execution in the order that it was started?

Given this code as an example:

```
class Foo {
    public fooPromise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    public value = null;

    public async setValue(v) {
        await this.fooPromise;
        this.value = v;
    }
}

async function main() {
    const foo = new Foo();
    foo.setValue(1);
    foo.setValue(2);
    foo.setValue(3);
    await foo.fooPromise;
    console.log(foo.value);
}

main();
```

Can it be assumed that the output will be `3`? Notice that function `main()` won't stop execution when calling `foo.setValue(x)`, and then wait for promise resolution in `await foo.fooPromise`, so at that time we will have 4 awaits waiting for `foo.fooPromise` to resolve.

*This code is just an example, to do something like that I wouldn't use this pattern. In my case, I have a 3rd party library that gets initialized eventually, and I want the consumers of my class to assume that's synchronous, that they can call my methods whenever they want and the result will be consistent: So if they set a setting twice, the value set will be the last one*

Comment: `Can it be assumed that the output will be 3?`,  No.    `and I want the consumers of my class to assume that's synchronous` you can't.   Your best option is to place the requests into a stack, and at least have some method of getting the results, that either returns a callback or another Promise.

Comment: Well, technically, I can. Just make `setValue` not async, save this in an private field and once the api is available set that last value that was stored. But this adds in the complexity of also having to track the `isApiAvailableYet`

Comment: `Well, technically, I can. Just make setValue not async`  then what's the point of your question?    What is `isApiAvailableYet` going to do?

Comment: `then what's the point of your question` That if it could be assumed that the resolve order is preserved, then there'd be no need to add that additional complexity. I'll just take that `No` as the answer, although experimentally it does preserve it.

Comment: `although experimentally it does preserve it`, try changing your timeout's to be random...

Comment: @Keith, making timeout random wouldn't change anything since there is only one promise that is built on class construction. He'd also need to make it so a new Promise is created for every setValue call.

Comment: `try changing your timeout's to be random...` this shouldn't hae any effect: there's only 1 timeout being created/executed. All awaiting get unlocked at the same timeout, because they are awaiting the same promise/timeout. It doesn't matter if that timeout has 0-delay or 1-year-delay.

Comment: @olivarra1 There is 6 promises been created above.

Comment: @Keith A promise is created only when you create a new instance of `Foo`. That's basic javascript....

Comment: @Ozam.  There is more than 1 promise here.

Comment: @olivarra1  `public async setValue(v) {`  creates a promise, that's basic Javascript.

Comment: It does create a promise, but not the one with the timeout, and it's a promise that's not being used anywhere, unless the consumer calls `await foo.setValue(x)`- Can we please not use these comments to chat?

Comment: @olivarra1  I must admit, with Op using typescript for some reason I was thinking ` this.fooPromise;` was creating a new invocation.  I was also assuming setValue would be doing more async stuff, since it was marked async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is only one promise, and **they all wait on the same promise**, yes, you can. Because the **registered callbacks of a promise will execute in the order they were registered**.

In your code:

```
foo.setValue(1); // => this will execute first and set value to 1
foo.setValue(2); // => this will execute second and set value to 2
foo.setValue(3); // => this will execute third and set value to 3
await foo.fooPromise; // => this will make the console.log wait for the previous three setValue calls
console.log(foo.value); // => it will always print 3
```

If you had created a new promise inside `setValue` instead of waiting the same promise, then you'd not be sure of the `console.log` result.

Comment: Your assuming `setValue` is always going to take the same time,..  So the result could end up been 1,2 or 3..  Also there is more than 1 promise here.

Comment: @Keith look carefully, there is only one promise that is created on class construction.

Comment: Each `foo.setValue` is creating a new Promise.

Comment: No, they are not. They all referense to `this.fooPromise` that the mockup code assumes that is created on constructor. You are probably confused because OP's code is not valid javascript class, but the intent is clear. OP should probably edit the question with valid javascript code to clear this misunderstanding because right now we both could be right, depending on which assumption you take with the mockup code.

Comment: `OP's code is not valid javascript class`, I think you hit the nail on the head.  The OP, has not even tagged this TypeScript,

Comment: they absolutely do create a new promises... that is what `await` does. `foo.setValue(1);` will create a promise and return immediately. It isn't being awaited and so the other `setValue` calls will also create promises. The promises that 'setValue' create will then wait for 'fooPromise' to resolve, and then it will run `this.value = v;` The end result is 3 because you are relying on the order the promises were created and their place in the event loop

Comment: Can we please ignore the promises created inside `setValue` because they are not relevant to the code? I'm sorry it's also not javascript, I use typescript and thought the syntax was pretty much similar. Editing the tags now